# Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS startup script java file

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitblit

I have configured Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS with a git client named gitblit: http://gitblit.com/

To start the gitblit client i need to start the terminal and type the next command: java -jar gitblit.jar every time i start up the ubuntu server.

Is there a way to autostart this line "java -jar gitblit.jar" with a script or something. I know there was chkconfig but its not supported by ubuntu server 14.

I have tried several codes like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/99232/how-to-make-a-jar-file-run-on-startup-and-when-you-log-out

@Magnus Back:
When i run this line: "bash -x /etc/init.d/gitblit start" in the terminal it says te following:

```
start-stop-daemon: user 'admin' not found
+ exit 0
```

The script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          gitblit
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Gitblit repository server
# Description:       Gitblit is a stand-alone service for managing, viewing and serving Git repositories.
### END INIT INFO

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

# change theses values (default values)
GITBLIT_PATH=/var/www/gitblit
GITBLIT_BASE_FOLDER=/var/www/gitblit/data
GITBLIT_USER="admin"
source ${GITBLIT_PATH}/java-proxy-config.sh
ARGS="-server -Xmx1024M ${JAVA_PROXY_CONFIG} -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar gitblit.jar --baseFolder $GITBLIT_BASE_FOLDER --dailyLogFile"

RETVAL=0

case "$1" in
  start)
    if [ -f $GITBLIT_PATH/gitblit.jar ];
      then
      echo $"Starting gitblit server"
      start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --oknodo --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/gitblit.pid --exec /usr/bin/java --chuid $GITBLIT_USER --chdir $GITBLIT_PATH -- $ARGS
      exit $RETVAL
    fi
  ;;

  stop)
    if [ -f $GITBLIT_PATH/gitblit.jar ];
      then
      echo $"Stopping gitblit server"
      start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/gitblit.pid
      exit $RETVAL
    fi
  ;;

  force-reload|restart)
      $0 stop
      sleep 5
      $0 start
  ;;

  *)
    echo $"Usage: /etc/init.d/gitblit {start|stop|restart|force-reload}"
    exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

So i think to add a new user but how or which. Also i fond another script for starting Gitblit

But when you download gitblit, in the zip there are files like:
instal-service.sh with the following lines

```
cp gitblit /etc/init.d/
chmod +x /etc/init.d/gitblit
sudo update-rc.d gitblit defaults
```

Also i have found another script maybe you could help me to makes this script to work

```
set -e

    GITBLIT_PATH=/opt/gitblit
    GITBLIT_HTTP_PORT=0
    GITBLIT_HTTPS_PORT=8443
    JAVA="java -server -Xmx1024M -jar"

    . /lib/lsb/init-functions

    case "$1" in
      start)
            log_action_begin_msg "Starting gitblit server"
            cd $GITBLIT_PATH
            $JAVA $GITBLIT_PATH/gitblit.jar --httpsPort $GITBLIT_HTTPS_PORT --httpPort $GITBLIT_HTTP_PORT > /dev/null &
            log_action_end_msg $?
            ;;
      stop)
            log_action_begin_msg "Stopping gitblit server"
            cd $GITBLIT_PATH
            $JAVA $GITBLIT_PATH/gitblit.jar --stop > /dev/null &
            log_action_end_msg $?
            ;;
      force-reload|restart)
            $0 stop
            $0 start
            ;;
      *)
            echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/gitblit {start|stop|restart|force-reload}"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac

    exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the autostart up for gitblit by following this tutorial:

http://kchard.github.io/gitblit-quickstart/

In this tutorial you will create a gitblit user named gitblit. I used instead the root user, and everytings works find.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write an init script. Go to your `/etc/` folder and copy the `/etc/skeleton`. There you can insert your line and then you can init that script as service in different run levels.

https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/blob/master/src/main/distrib/linux/service-ubuntu.sh

Comment: I have created a file gitblit.sh and saved it in /etc/init.d with the copied code from: https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/blob/master/src/main/distrib/linux/service-ubuntu.sh

Then in the terminal i entered this codes

sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/gitblit
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/gitblit

sudo update-rc.d gitblit defaults
sudo update-rc.d gitblit enable

But it still doens't work

Comment: @Bham: What did you expect would've happened? The steps you took look reasonable. Did you adjust the paths in the script (e.g. GITBLIT_PATH)?

Comment: @Magnus Back: i have changed the paths location where gitblit is stored in my case it is /var/www/gitblit. But it stil doesnt work.  is there in Ubuntu a simpel way to just execute this rule java -jar gitblit.jar" when Ubuntu starts because thats all i need

Comment: @Bham: _What_ doesn't work? What happens when you run `/etc/init.d/gitblit start` as root? Does it start? If not, what if you run `bash -x /etc/init.d/gitblit start` instead? Any interesting clues in the resulting log?